# DISTINCT not giving expected result

Tags: sql, subquery, average, aggregate-functions, distinct

```
ID  FirstName   LastName    Gender  Salary
1   Ben         Hoskins     Male    70000
2   Mark        Hastings    Male    60000
4   Ben         Hoskins     Male    70000
8   John        Stanmore    Male    80000
```

While running the query:

```
select *
from Employees
where  Salary > (SELECT AVG(distinct SALARY) FROM employees)
```

It is displaying 2 records for 7000 it should display one. Why is it showing 2 records if I have used distinct?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, postgres...?

Comment: What is your aim, ıf you want to show only the people that takes more than avg(salary), why will you use distinct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used `distinct` the subquery, not in the outer query, so the outer query still sees the data with the duplicates.

You *could* solve this using:

```
select e.FirstName, e.LastName, e.Gender, e.Salary
from Employees e
where e.Salary > (SELECT AVG(distinct e2.SALARY) FROM employees e2);
```

However, something seems seriously wrong with the data model if you have rows with such duplicates.  The data should be fixed.

In the meantime, you can work around the problem.  You can phrase your query using a CTE that eliminates the duplicates:

```
with e as (
      select e.*
      from (select e.*,
                   row_number(). over (partition by firstname, lastname, gender order by id desc) as seqnum
            from employees e
           )
      where seqnum = 1
     )
select e.*
from e
where e.salary > (select avg(salary) from e)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have duplicate rows in the table (that only differ by their `id`), so I am going to assume that you want `distinct` over the name, gender and salary rather than the salary only.

You seem to want `distinct` both in the outer and inner query:

```
select distinct firstname, lastname, gender, salary
from employees
where salary > (
    select avg(salary)
    from (
        select distinct firstname, lastname, gender, salary
        from employees
    ) e
)
```

If your database supports window functions, this can be shortened:

```
select *
from (
    select e.*, avg(salary) over() as avg_salary
    from (
        select distinct firstname, lastname, gender, salary
        from employees
    ) e
) e
where salary > avg_salary
```